# Como realizar una suma del resultado de una consulta ?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

Espero me puedan apoyar, necesito realizar la suma del resultado de los salarios que me arrojo la consulta anterior. El resultado que necesito solo seria $17,500

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado hacer sum(c.Salario) ?

Comment: Si amigo ya intente eso pero no es la solución :(

Comment: Pero debes quitar el GROUP BY e.Id_Emp y dejar el FROM igual que en la consulta original

Comment: Supongo que sólo necesitas ese resultado, la suma de los salarios, que las otras columnas del `SELECT` no te interesan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
SELECT SUM(tabla.Salario)
FROM (
    SELECT e.Nombre,e.Paterno,e.Materno,d.Nombre as Departamento, p.Descripcion as 
    Puesto,c.Salario
    FROM empleado e
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT ID_emp,MAX(Fecha_Inicio),ID_depto,ID_puesto
      FROM labora
      GROUP BY ID_emp,ID_depto,ID_puesto
    ) as l
    ON e.ID_emp=l.ID_emp
    INNER JOIN departamento d ON l.ID_Depto=d.ID_Depto
    INNER JOIN puesto p ON l.ID_puesto=p.ID_puesto
    INNER JOIN contiene c ON l.ID_puesto=c.ID_puesto AND d.ID_depto=c.ID_depto
) AS tabla
```

El `GROUP BY` interno que tienes está mal, ya que si utilizas una función agregada y los agrupas, debes agrupar por las columnas, es decir por `ID_emp`,`ID_depto`,`ID_puesto`